# Update each record with a random number within a range

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to update employee table with a value generated randomly from the 
generate_series(9353500001234, 9353500001237) and also need to make sure that the duplicate values should not be updated. 
When i try to join employee table with the generate_series it results in cross product. Please advice

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
  member_number integer,
  gs1_src_acct_num bigint,
  CONSTRAINT employee_gs1_src_acct_num_key UNIQUE (gs1_src_acct_num)
)  
INSERT INTO lcdm_lnd.employee(member_number) VALUES (7360909);
INSERT INTO lcdm_lnd.employee(member_number) VALUES (3142554);
INSERT INTO lcdm_lnd.employee(member_number) VALUES (1510423);
INSERT INTO lcdm_lnd.employee(member_number) VALUES (9605961);
```

Comment: What field do you want to update?

Comment: gs1_src_acct_num need to be populated by picking a value randomly within the range between 9353500001234 and 9353500001237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
update employee
    set gs1_src_acct_num = e2.new_gs1_src_acct_num
    from (select e2.*,
                 (row_number() over (order by random()) - 1 + 9353500001234) as new_gs1_src_acct_num
          from employee e2
         ) e2
     where e2.member_number = e.member_number;
```